# I wants to do default sharing from application which are installed in device.Twitter and facebook share Text and image in android

Tags: android

I am new to android in my application i am using default sharing. After clicking share button when i login to twitter i get text for tweet but problem in fetching image from my application and also tweet button disable after login.
Here is my code for sharing

```
File cacheDir = new File(
                android.os.Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(),
                getString(getApplicationInfo().labelRes));
        File f = new File(cacheDir, ImgName);

        intent = new Intent(android.content.Intent.ACTION_SEND);
        intent.setType("text/plain");
        intent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT,
                Title_name);
        intent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_TEXT,
                discription);
        intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, Uri.fromFile(f));

        try {
            startActivity(Intent.createChooser(intent, "share via"));
        } catch (android.content.ActivityNotFoundException ex) {
            Toast.makeText(Activity.this,
                    "There are no email clients installed.",
                    Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

You are setting type explicitly to text/plain. Try to set that type to image/*.